# Fastest raspberry pi 3 os other than raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, kali

When I  first got my raspberry pi 3 I had raspian on it but I didn't like it very much so I put kali linux on it and it was even slower than raspbian. Is there any other raspberry pi os that is fast and won't crash on watching youtube videos?

I also overclocked my raspberry pi but it was still slow on browsing on kali.

I am also a 'noob' to linux.

**Any help will be greatly appreciated**

Comment: Are you talking about boot time (which is highly distribution related) or run-time performance? There should not be that much runtime speed diffference between different Linux distributions using glibc and even less between the Debian based ones like Kali and Ubuntu. Boot-time is a completely different topic.

Comment: @Sven Geggus run-time performance, i don't really care on the boot times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Ubuntu Mate 
Or 
Windows iot core  but use class 10 sdcard  in my opinion  this one is better for watching YouTube videos 
If looking for light weight Os  go for dietpi it's fast light weight.